# Selecting by id when collection isn't known

Tags: mongodb, solr4

I'm using Apache Solr to index and search against my mongo database. When I index an entity in Solr, I save only the ID of that entity so that I can retrieve the full result from mongo. The problem is that because I'm only saving the ID, I don't know which collection that ID is in. So, here's what I'm thinking about, and input on any of these options would be great (or other options I haven't thought of)

**Is it possible to search across all collections to find the appropriate entity by its ID?**

- If this is possible, is it prone to being slow/inefficient?

**Since the above approach doesn't seem very good to me, is it possible to create a compound index that could be used to find the appropriate entity in the appropriate collection?**

**Along with the ID, save the name of the collection in Solr, and return that along with the search results**

- While this seems best from an efficiency standpoint, it seems like I might be creating problems for myself down the road if/when I need to change the names of collections, or add new ones

**Edit:**
I'm using mongo's native ObjectId for the ID, so the ids should be unique across all collections

Answer (score 0):

for first part of your question, check this: [Get a document in MongoDB without specifying collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728196/get-a-document-in-mongodb-without-specifying-collection)

yes it is definitely possible to create a compound index. you can create something like {type}+"--"+{id} to create unique indexes in your app. more often than not, you will know which collection to query to search by id.