# MongoDB: Find an object by its ID without knowing the collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, robo3t

I have an mongodb databse with 100+ collections. I'm trying to find an object, with a known ObjectID, that belongs to some (unknown) collection of this database.

I tried to do:

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collname) {
    var object = db[collname].find({'_id' : ObjectId("54d0232ef83ea4000d2c0610")});
    if(object._id !== undefined){
        printjson("Found in " >> collname);
    }
});
```

... similar to what's suggested here: [Loop through all Mongo collections and execute query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25543452/loop-through-all-mongo-collections-and-execute-query)

However, I am getting no results from the script.

Edit:

When I do this I get the expected `Found!`:

```
var object = db['rightcollection'].findOne({'_id' : ObjectId("54d0232ef83ea4000d2c0610")});
if(object !== null){
    printjson("Found!");
}
```

But the following returns `0` (instead of returning nothing as in the original example):

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collname) {
    var object = db[collname].findOne({'_id' : ObjectId("54d0232ef83ea4000d2c0610")});
    if(object !== null){
        printjson("Found in " >> collname);
    }
});
```

Comment: Try `var object = db[collname].find({'_id' : ObjectId("54d0232ef83ea4000d2c0610")});`. Notice changed `id` to `_id`

Comment: Try using `findOne` instead of `find`.

Comment: @Veeram `id`instead of `_id` was just a typo. I edited the original post.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Using `findOne` I get `TypeError: object is null :
@(shell):3:1
@(shell):1:1`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

try this:

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collName) {
  var doc = db.getCollection(collName).findOne({"_id" : ObjectId("54d0232ef83ea4000d2c0610")});
  if(doc != null) print(doc._id + " was found in " + collName); 
});
```

using db.getCollection

Edit: you can get more detailed info on this question: [Get a document in MongoDB without specifying collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728196/get-a-document-in-mongodb-without-specifying-collection)

Comment: the id doesn't have to be of type ObjectId

Comment: yeah you are right i just copy pasted the example of the question changing only the method to get the collection. I'll edit

Comment: Worked for me adding the ObjectId() method


```var doc = db.getCollection(collName).findOne({"_id" : ObjectId("54d0232ef83ea4000d2c0610")});```
  


Thanks